# Incremental loading with pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a few sources of data (let's say these are users events).
Each source, has it's own events definitions. 
While loading to HCatalog I create one table with `event_definitions (event_id, event_code, event_source, evend_description)`, and one with `events(event_is, date, etc...)`
These tables are unions of all date from source tables.

`event_definitions.event_id` is a surrogate key, which is a foreign key for `events.event_id`

This key is taken from pig RANK function.
And everything works fine while initial loading.
But how do i serve incremetal loading? New values in event_definitions table must bigger surrogate key vale than last one. With RANK the is no posibility to start with exact numer. It always starts with number 1.

How do you serve these situations?

Regards
Paweł

Comment: Is there any additional information in the rows that tell you what the source is?  That is, could you look at two rows from different files and tell that they are different?  Also, does your key need to be an integer?

Comment: the obviously doesn't have to be int. But nevertheless the main question is - is it possible to increment values in RANK?

Comment: i'm expecting something like this: event_definitions = LOAD 'stage.event_definitions' USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
a = foreach event_definitions generate evde_id, evde_code;
id = foreach a generate evde_id;
ordered_id = order id by evde_id desc;
max_id = limit ordered_id 1;
events = foreach cis generate evde_code;
events_rank = rank events;
events_incr = foreach events_rank generate flatten($0)+1;

Comment: "Obviously" I don't know the details of your situation so I can't make any assumptions when thinking how to answer. There's a billion ways to do this. Append the file name, create a job ID, remember the last one and add that to the value `RANK` gives. I'm sure you'll come up with something.

Comment: I like you solution: remember the last one and add that to the value RANK gives. But it doen't work in my scripts ... Take a look at my previous comment.